# SQL Result: Non-empty categories

Tags: sql, linq

The difficult here may be the result of bad table design, feel free to give an answer with a different design if it simplifies things. I am still learning normalization techniques.

I have a parts database, and for the scope of this question it looks like this:

```
Parts           Manufacturers   Categories  PartCategories
PartId          ManufacturerId  CategoryId  CategoryId
Name            Name            Name        PartId
ManufacturerId
```

Foreign Keys should be obvious from the structure. A part can only have one manufacturer, but it can be in multiple categories. If this design is bad, please comment on whats wrong with it (I want to learn).

The idea is, when looking, you will select a manufacturer, then a category, and see the list of parts. The list of categories is the same for each manufacturer, but not every manufacture has parts in every category. Some will be empty. I want the list of categories to only represent non-empty categories though, so I need a way to build a list of which categories have parts for which manufacturers. I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to generate this list, either from SQL or linq-to-entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Categories.Name,
  ...
FROM
  Categories
  INNER JOIN PartCategories ON PartCategories.CategoryId=Categories.CategoryId
  INNER JOIN Parts ON PartCategories.PartId=Parts.PartId
  INNER JOIN Manufacturers on Parts.ManufacturerId=Manufacturers.ManufacturerId
WHERE
  Manufacturers.ManufacturerId=<your chosen ManufacturerId>
```

The idea is to use only those Categories, that can be joined to a part, that can itself be joined to the chosen Manufacturer.

@Thyrsius: Thanks for feedback, Corrected.

Comment: The parts table has no categoryid column. Its related through the PartCategories table

Comment: Removing the where clause gives me the almost the result I was looking for, so I am marking this as accepted. All I did was add a distinct.

Answer (score 1):

For a given `@ManufacterIdToBeChecked`:

```
SELECT
      c.CategoryId
    , c.Name
FROM
    Categories AS c
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM PartCategories AS pc
          JOIN Parts AS p
            ON p.PartId = pc.PartId 
        WHERE pc.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
          AND p.ManufacturerId = @ManufacterIdToBeChecked
      )
```

To build a list of all compatible `ManufacturerId` and `CategoryId`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      p.ManufacturerId
    , pc.CategoryId
FROM 
        Parts AS p
    JOIN 
        PartCategories AS pc  ON pc.PartId = p.PartId
```

Comment: The parts table has no categoryid column. Its related through the PartCategories table

Comment: Is your second procedure complete? I would expect input parameters for `ManufacturerId` and `CategoryId` respectively and return a resultset of parts.